# jQuery mobile toggle button on/off?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

as far as I can see the standard jQuery 'toggle' function does not work in jQuery mobile - is this correct? If so, is there another method that does work? All I'm trying to do is toggle a 'play' button on and off.. so the button id is "playbtn" and I'm setting a variable up so when it's clicked once the audio file plays and the button changes to "pause" - when clicked again the button says"Play" and the audio file stops.

Thanks for any light you can shed..

Jim

Comment: Hey, is this what you looking for - http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/switch/ hope it helps. T

Comment: Hi - that's a great help - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. You have to 'refresh' the jquery mobile element.

```
$('.toggleswitch')[0].selectedIndex = 1;
$('.toggleswitch').slider('refresh');
```